# Dart is there any way to invoke onDone callback from stream.listen() where the stream is from StreamController

Tags: dart

I'm trying to extends `StreamConsumer`, this is how I implement it :

```
import 'dart:async';

class Consumer extends StreamConsumer {
  List list = new List();
  StreamSubscription subscription;

  Future addStream(Stream stream) {
    Completer c = new Completer();
    subscription = stream.listen((d) => list.add(d),
        onError: c.completeError,
        onDone: () => c.complete(this));
    return c.future;
  }

  Future close() {
    subscription.cancel();
    return new Future.value(this);
  }
}

void main() {
  List data = [1,2,3,4,5];
  Stream stream = new Stream.fromIterable(data);
  Consumer streamConsumer = new Consumer();
  stream.pipe(streamConsumer).then((Consumer consumer) {
    print(consumer.list);
  });
}
```

As expected, it prints `[1,2,3,4,5]` but if I change the implementation of the `Stream` to something like this :

```
StreamController controller = new StreamController();
Stream stream = controller.stream;
controller.add(1);
controller.add(2);
controller.add(3);
stream.pipe(streamConsumer).then((Consumer consumer) {
  print(consumer.list);
});
controller.add(4);
controller.add(5);
```

It prints nothing. It can be concluded that the `onDone` callback isn't called at all (I think). So any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `StreamController.close()`

`new Stream.fromIterable(data)` basically creates a StreamController, adds the elements of the iterable one at a time, and closes the controller when the iteration is complete. In your second code block you're doing this manually, but just not closing the controller.

Here's the relevant docs: http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_async/StreamController.html#close